# Removing an arbitrary element from a priority queue

Tags: python, heap, priority-queue

I am working on the following- "For this task, you will be implementing an EditablePatientHeapQueue, which enables arbitrary patient deletion (by name) in O(log n) time using a new remove method. As with most efficiency improvements, we have traded space for time: we will store the index of every patient in a Python dictionary self.indices, keyed by their name. This way, finding a patient is O(1) time, so the dominant operation is the subsequent sifting of the replacement. The wrinkle in the plan is that we need to keep track of where a patient is stored, even when sifting. For this reason, you should provide a new version of the enqueue, dequeue, and _swap methods which take the new self.indices dictionary into account."

My implementation

```
class EditablePatientHeapQueue(PatientHeapQueue):
    """ Implement a queue structure using a 0-indexed heap. This particular type of queue holds patient information. Additionally, we can remove patients not at the top of the heap in O(log n) time. """

    def __init__(self, start_data=None, fast=False):
        self.indices = {}  # name -> index;
                           # Keep track of where patients are stored
        for (i, person) in enumerate(start_data):
            self.indices[person.name] = i
        super().__init__(start_data, fast)


    def _swap(self, i, j):
        """ Swap patients at index i and j. Don't forget to change
            their position in self.indices as well!
        """   

        self.indices[self.data[i].name] = j
        self.indices[self.data[j].name] = i    
        self.data[i], self.data[j] = self.data[j], self.data[i]        


    def remove(self, patient_name):
        """ Remove the particular patient from the heap. Remember,
            the index will tell you where the patient is in the heap
            and every sub-heap below an index forms a valid heap.
        """

        #Dictionary self.indices- key (patient name) : value (index)
        #Heap self.data- patient name, priority 

        #Step 1: Find the patient in O(1) time and remove from the heap and dictionary

        #Retrieve the index for the patient name in O(1) time 
        patient_index = self.indices[patient_name] 
        end = len(self.data)-1

        #Swap patients 
        self._swap(patient_index, end)

        #Remove the patient from the heap and dictionary
        del self.data[end]  
        del self.indices[patient_name]

        #Step 2: Reheapify

        #Parent is greater than patient index then sift down 
        if patient_index != 0 and self.data[patient_index].priority < self.data[super()._parent_index(patient_index)].priority:
            super()._sift_down(patient_index)

        #Patient index is greater than parent then sift up 
        else:
            super()._sift_up(patient_index) 


    def enqueue(self, patient):
        """ Add a patient to the queue. 
        """
        assert isinstance(patient, Patient)
        self.data.append(patient)
        self.indices[patient.name] = len(self.data)-1
        super()._sift_up(len(self.data)-1)


    def dequeue(self):
        """ Remove a patient from the front of the queue and return them.
        """

        if len(self.data) == 0:
           return None
        elif len(self.data) == 1:
           del self.indices[self.data[0].name]
           return self.data.pop(0)
        else:
           patient = self.data[0]
           self.data[0] = self.data[len(self.data)-1] 
           self.indices[patient.name] = 0
           del self.indices[patient.name]
           del self.data[len(self.data)-1]  
           super()._sift_down(0)
           return patient
```

I am getting the following error- 1 builtins.AssertionError: Heap invariant violated!/AssertionError: Bad heap invariant after 'remove':
    parent: Patient(Elizabeth Battles, 2676)
    child: Patient(Jonathan Bianchi, 63801)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're not adding an entry to `self.indices` when you enqueue an item.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks so much I have now added the following self.indices[patient.name] = len(self.data)-1 to the enqueue method which has helped resolve the first error which was builtins.KeyError: 'Juan Daudelin' for patient_index = self.indices[patient_name] in the remove method. But I am still getting the second error builtins.KeyError: Patient(Robert Rogers, 122209) for del self.indices[patient] in the dequeue method. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems in your code.

The first is that you're not adding an entry to `self.indices` when you enqueue an item. So when you try to look up a patient name in the dictionary, it's not there.

In your `dequeue` method, you have this code:

```
    elif len(self.data) == 1:
        return self.data.pop()
    else:
        patient = self.data[0]
        self.data[0] = self.data[len(self.data)-1] 
        del self.indices[patient]
        del self.data[len(self.data)-1]  
        super()._sift_down(0)
        return patient
```

In the `elif` case, you have to remove the item from `self.indices`.

In the `else` case, I see two problems. On the second line, you move the item from the end of the heap to the top of the heap. That's fine, but then you have to change its index in the dictionary. I think you want to add this line:

```
self.indicies[self.data[0].patientName] = 0
```

Otherwise your code is going to fail when it tries to sift that item down.

For the delete error, I think your problem is that you're trying to index `indices` by the patient rather than the patient name. I'd suggest replacing this line:

```
del self.indices[patient]
```

with

```
del self.indices[patient.name]
```

In your `remove` method, you have this:

```
    #Remove the patient from the heap and dictionary
    del self.data[end]  
    del self.indices[patient_name]

    #Step 2: Reheapify
```

You might want to consider what happens next if the item you're deleting is the last item on the heap. `patient_index` will be indexing beyond the end of `self.data`.

For the future, you might consider learning how to use the debugger to add breakpoints and single-step your code. That allows you to watch the state of all your data structures. For example, had you single-stepped the `dequeue` method, you would have been able to see that you're passing a `patient` rather than a patient's name as an index to the dictionary. A good resource is Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Hi Jim, I have edited the dequeue method with your recommendations but now I am getting the following error- AssertionError: Bad heap invariant after 'remove':
parent: Patient(Elizabeth Battles, 2676)
child: Patient(Jonathan Bianchi, 63801). So the heap is no longer a valid heap but I can't find where I have gone wrong in the remove method. I have based my remove method code on the delete algorithm from http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/9-BinTree/heap-delete.html. Thanks again.

Comment: @Turquoise25: I don't see how that's an invalid heap. The parent's priority is 2676, which is lower than the child's 63801. Assuming this is a min heap, then that's correct. If it's supposed to be a max heap, then the problem is with the comparison in your `remove` method. I can't identify the problem by looking at your code.

Comment: @Turquoise25: Also see my update above where I identify another potential problem in `remove`. What happens if the node you're removing is the last node in the heap?

Comment: Hi Jim, I checked my remove method code and realized I had the sift down and sift up method round the wrong way which I have now edited. I still get the AssertionError: Bad heap invariant after 'remove': parent: Patient(Elizabeth Battles, 2676) child: Patient(Jonathan Bianchi, 63801) and also I am now getting IndexError: list index out of range for patient_index != 0 and self.data[patient_index].priority < self.data[super()._parent_index(patient_index)].priority for the remove method. Thanks again.

Comment: Also for removing the last node in the heap isn't this taken care of by swapping before the deletion from the heap and dictionary?

Comment: @Turquoise25: On the removal, you might be right. As for the other errors, I don't know how to help you. I don't have a python dev environment set up, and I don't have all of your code or your test data. You'll have to debug it yourself. I would suggest inserting some diagnostic output statements in your code, and learning to use the debugger. Also, read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).